# React onScroll not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add onscroll event handler to specific dom element. Look at this code:

```
class ScrollingApp extends React.Component {
    ...
    _handleScroll(ev) {
        console.log("Scrolling!");
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.list.addEventListener('scroll', this._handleScroll);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.refs.list.removeEventListener('scroll', this._handleScroll);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="list">
                {
                    this.props.items.map( (item) => {
                        return (<Item item={item} />);
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Code is quite simple, and as you can see, I want to handle div#list scrolling. When I was running this example, it isn't working. So I tried bind this._handleScroll on render method directly, it doesn't work either.

```
<div ref="list" onScroll={this._handleScroll.bind(this)> ... </div>
```

So i opened chrome inspector, adding onscroll event directly with:

```
document.getElementById('#list').addEventListener('scroll', ...);
```

and it is working! I don't know why this happens. Is this a bug of React or something? or did I missed something? Any device will very appreciated.

Comment: It's working for me (http://www.webpackbin.com/V1ECCW5Vb), scroll within the block and then click the "Log" button at top of page to see the logs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The root of the problem is that `this.refs.list` is a React component, not a DOM node. To get the DOM element, which has the `addEventListener()` method, you need to call `ReactDOM.findDOMNode()`:

```
class ScrollingApp extends React.Component {

    _handleScroll(ev) {
        console.log("Scrolling!");
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const list = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.list)
        list.addEventListener('scroll', this._handleScroll);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        const list = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.list)
        list.removeEventListener('scroll', this._handleScroll);
    }
    /* .... */
}
```

Comment: `findDOMNode` is deprecated.  Instead of setting your div ref to "list" you need to set it up using `<div ref={node => this.list = node}` and then your mount/unmount functions can access the variable directly, without having to find the node, `this.list.addEventListener(...`