# React onScroll not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I have simple react component, I set onScroll event to that component but when I scroll it's not firing

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  _handleScroll(e) {
    console.log('scrolling')
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      width: '100px',
      height: '100px',
      overflowY: 'hidden'
    }
    const innerDiv = {
      height: '300px',
      width: '100px',
      background: '#efefef'
    }
    return (
      <div style={style} onScroll={this._handleScroll}>
        <div style={innerDiv}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725828/update-style-of-a-component-onscroll-in-react-js

Answer (score 23):

You need to change the value of `overflowY` to `auto` or `scroll`. Right now you're not getting a scrollbar because `hidden` causes the browser to hide the scrollbar.

Comment: general solution for this bug, thank you sir, I had overflow: hidden on the <html>

Comment: Thank you nathan!

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your answer! Notice: you also need to fix an height to trigger the event

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a ref to the DOM element:

[React onScroll not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831129/react-onscroll-not-working)

```
class ScrollingApp extends React.Component {

    _handleScroll(ev) {
        console.log("Scrolling!");
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const list = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.list)
        list.addEventListener('scroll', this._handleScroll);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        const list = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.list)
        list.removeEventListener('scroll', this._handleScroll);
    }
    /* .... */
}
```