# onScroll event neither triggers nor gives top in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brWbQZ?editors=1111

```
class Application extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div onScroll={ () => console.log('scroll') }>...</div>;
    }
}
```

When I get things working with onWheel there isn't a single properties that indicates change in scroll position. scrollTop, y, offset, page, etc. Neither on window, document, body, nor the target.

Can someone please give me a working example of an element of an abitrary height giving scroll position in react.

(This is not a duplicate, because onScroll is applied to a div and I'm looking for additional information. Frankly, it's not even close to the same question.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React onScroll not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831129/react-onscroll-not-working)

Comment: Likely a CSS setting.  I've found that elements with a  min-height set will not trigger the onScroll..

Answer (score 0):

Actually scroll is working, but it is triggered on `window`, that's why all of the implementations you may came across use `window.addEventListener('scroll',...)`.

But if you add CSS properties to your div as i did in [this example](https://codepen.io/rlax/pen/EegOeN?editors=1111) scroll will be triggered on your div, and thus onScroll (react synthetic event) will fire as expected.